# leading superscript in plotmath expression (w/ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I'd like to use `plotmath` to create an axis containing a leading superscript in a `ggplot2` plot. Creating superscripts on axis labels works nicely, like so:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(x[y]))
```

[image]

However, I'd like to have my axis label read "y(superscript)x" - logically that would be `^yx`, but that won't parse:

```
Error: unexpected '^' in: "  
geom_point() + 
ylab(expression(^"
```

Is there a way to force a superscript at the beginning of a statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(phantom(0)^y * x))
```

I was certain there must be a way to do a "placeholder" character, but I had to scroll down a bit in `?plotmath` to find it.

Comment: Probably could have just used an empty doubled-quote as well. `expression(""^y * x)`