# Adding superscript to graph in R with no preceding character

Tags: r, superscript

I'm trying to add a text in the form of **<sup>a</sup>b** to a graph instead of **a<sup>b</sup>**.

This works fine:

```
> xlab = expression(paste("a"^"b"))
```

If I reverse them I get:

```
Error: unexpected '^' in "xlab = expression(paste(^"
```

What would be the correct way to implement it?

Comment: `plot(1, xlab = expression(paste(""^"a", "b")))` or `plot(1, xlab = expression(''^a~b))`

Comment: related question: [leading superscript in plotmath expression (w/ggplot2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111606/leading-superscript-in-plotmath-expression-w-ggplot2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `phantom()`

```
plot(0, xlab = ~ phantom() ^ a * b)
```

[image: screenshot]